# Shortest code to limit return value to be between two values

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I have a method in my Android app that takes a dynamically set font size and returns a proportionally smaller font size. The value it gets from getTextSize() is for headlines and the smaller out value is for body text. Currently it's written as:

```
public int getSmallerTextSize(){
    int textSize = (int)Math.round(getTextSize() * 0.8);

    if(textSize > 20){
        textSize = 20;
    }else if(textSize < 10){
        textSize = 10;
    }

    return textSize;
}
```

I want to find a shorter and less clunky way to express this. One option is:

```
public int getSmallerTextSize(){
    int textSize = (int)Math.round(getTextSize() * 0.8);

    textSize = textSize > 10 ? textSize : 10;
    textSize = textSize > 20 ? 20 : textSize;

    return textSize;
}
```

But again: a lot of code for something so simple. Can someone suggest an elegant preferrably one-liner of code to express this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use the following expression:

```
textSize = Math.min(Math.max(textSize,10),20);
```

Comment: Thanks, short and beautiful. I picked this as answer since it's short (I asked for a one-liner...) and despite its shortness it is IMHO clear what it means.

Comment: You have my vote for answering the question asked, but this is definitely slower because you are guaranteed to call two different methods every time.

Answer (score 4):

You could create a `limitRange` helper method.

```
public static int limitRange(int i, int min, int max) {
    if (i > max) {
        i = max;
    } else if (i < min) {
        i = min;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Then, use it as a one-liner whenever you need to limit an int's range:

```
public int getSmallerTextSize(){
    int textSize = (int)Math.round(getTextSize() * 0.8);
    textSize = limitRange(textSize, 10, 20);
    return textSize;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer explicit `return`s, and avoding `else` clauses when unnecessary.

```
public int getSmallerTextSize() {
    int textSize = (int) Math.round(getTextSize() * 0.8);
    if (textSize < 10) {
        return 10;
    }
    if (textSize > 20) {
        return 20;
    }
    return textSize;
}
```

I would extract a `limitRange` method only if some other method used the same logic. Also, it may be nice to add a couple of constants holding the values of the range limits.

Answer (score 2):

**If you want to reduce the number of lines in the code(single line code)** then try merging both ternary operations in one line as below:

```
  int textSize = (int)Math.round(getTextSize() * 0.8);
  textSize = textSize>20 ?20:textSize<10 ?10: textSize ;
```